# Connecting to multiple databases with multiple threads

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I'm currently trying to connect to different computers in order to import records stored in each computer's local database. So far, the posts I've seen regarding connection pools is that it creates a pool of connections for a single database. Is there a way to create a connection to each computer using threads in order to make the task faster? If not, what's the most efficient way to connect to and disconnect from different computers?

Comment: I'm no expert in this field, but your question seems very broad to me.

Comment: Do you need multiple connections open at once? You could just loop over each "server" and import the records you need

Comment: I would prefer to be able to have multiple connections at once so the task can be finished faster. Is it a good approach to just have multiple Connection instances to the different servers? i.e. just open and close a new Connection in each Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public static void main(String... strings) {

//Pool of 5 threads
ExecutorService threadPool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<SQLServer> servers=new ArrayList<>();

SQLServer mySql1=new SQLServer();
mySql1.setUrl("jdbc://localhost:3306");
mySql1.setDatabase("testDb1");
mySql1.setUsername("admin");
mySql1.setPassword("root");
mySql1.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

SQLServer mySql2=new SQLServer();
mySql2.setUrl("jdbc://localhost:3306");
mySql2.setDatabase("testDb2");
mySql2.setUsername("admin");
mySql2.setPassword("root");
mySql2.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//You can add as many as you want.
servers.add(mySql1);
servers.add(mySql2);

servers.forEach(s->{
    SQLClient sqlClient=new SQLClient(s);
    threadPool.execute(sqlClient);
});
}

class SQLClient implements Runnable {
private SQLServer sqlServer;

public SQLClient(SQLServer server) {
sqlServer = server;
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
    Class.forName(sqlServer.getDriverClass());
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
Connection connection = null;

try {
    connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(sqlServer.getUrl()+"/"+sqlServer.getDatabase(),
        sqlServer.getUsername(), sqlServer.getPassword());

}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

if (connection != null) {
    System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");


    try {
    Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute("your query");
     // You can fetch you data here
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
}
}

}

class SQLServer {
String username;
String password;
String url;
String database;
String driverClass;

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public String getDatabase() {
return database;
}

public void setDatabase(String database) {
this.database = database;
}

public String getDriverClass() {
return driverClass;
}

public void setDriverClass(String driverClass) {
this.driverClass = driverClass;
}
}
```